# Initialise an array with numbers from 1 to n objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Very basic question. I need to initialise a NSMutableArray with values from 1 to n(or m to n, say). Is there anything I can do to initialise the array without using a for loop? I mean is there anything like:

`[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithSomeThing];`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about a `while loop`?

Comment: I actually meant without using any loops.

Comment: It's not possible, and if there was a method able to do that, it was using a loop.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT No, at some point there should be a loop, Quantum-Objective-C is far away. Also, this question is not about Xcode.

Comment: Crazy subclass that return the index for missing objects? *I'm kidding. a loop is most likely the way to go*

Comment: Just for the fun of it (don't _ever_ do stuff like that) :P https://gist.github.com/alladinian/6019910

Answer (score 7, accepted):

short answer: no

long answer: nope

the easiest is to look up the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see if it has something like that

Comment: this answer made me laugh :)

Comment: I like the long answer.

Comment: So unnecessary to have more than the short and long answer in this post :D

Answer (score 0):

`NSArrays` are meant to contain Objects.. An Object just containing an integer is quite an overload.

When it always starts at 1 an goes up to n why not just store the n value in a variable and when you would need your 1..n array just do a while from 1 till n

I do not get the point where one should need a 1..n NSArray and I think this is why there is no Method to do this with an `NSArray` / `NSMutableArray`

Comment: its hard to imagine a case where having an array from 1..n is useful, but i wouldnt assume that you know what he is trying to do with it. also `NSNumbers` are objects that contain integers, wouldnt say that is an overload

Comment: It is an overload because I can represent the total array by exactly one NSNumber. So rather than having 42894 NSNumbers you just need to save 42894 in a NSNumber and you can produce all the other Objects on demand. This is a huge overhead..

Comment: that is true, but again, you dont know what he is actually trying to do and maybe just storing one number isnt going to work

Comment: @Fonix if you reference something by index from 0..n then initially you have to create an array that contains numbers from 0..n. E.g. you have a tableview that can be re-ordered but you still want to have original references synchronized with cell indices; array index = cell index, value = some data reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a category method to do it like this:

```
@interface NSMutableArray(MyConvenienceMethods)

+(NSMutableArray*) arrayWithValuesFrom: (int) n to: (int) m step: (int) step;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray(MyConvenienceMethods)

+(NSMutableArray*) arrayWithValuesFrom: (int) n to: (int) m step: (int) step
{
    NSMutableArray* ret = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = n ; i <= m ; i += step) 
    {
        [ret addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: i]];
    }
    return ret;
}

@end
```

And you use it like this:

```
NSMutableArray* anArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithValuesFrom: 1 to: 100 step: 1];
```

Comment: This is a loop ;) The question asks for having a solution without looping. So like 1..n stuff in Lazy Languages like Haskell

Comment: @lukaswelte Yes, but it's only **one** loop in one place.  Ultimately, even if there was a built in initialiser in Cocoa, there would still be a loop in its implementation.

Comment: @lukaswelte and if you think there is no loop in the Haskell construct (or some equivalent like recursion), you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: No in Haskell you don't create all the objects before doing some stuff. You evaluate the function just when needed and only as far as needed. Thats why you can have a infinite list so 1..infinity

Comment: @lukaswelte But the implementation will involve looping or recursion in some form even if it is not done up front.  The implementation details are hidden from the user just as they are with my method.